# How to fix Eclipse Luna hanging/stuck on splash screen before asking for workspace?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-luna

I just updated Eclipse from the Juno release to the Luna release, but can't figure out why Luna won't start; it's not getting past the splash screen. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I edited the question to be a proper question; enter your resolution as an Answer below.

Comment: Sorry for that guys I'm new to posting on here.

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix for the my issue. I had to update JDK to JDK 7 and now Eclipse loads without any hanging.